# Reference request: Galois descent

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, galois-theory

What is a classic (perhaps even original) reference for Galois descent? I know that it can be seen as a special case of faithfully flat descent (for which FGA and SGA I is the usual reference) and that it can also be proven directly in a very elementary way. It is also presented in many new textbooks. But I would like to have a very old (and still useful) reference.

Comment: How old is "very old (and still useful)": 50 years?  And why are more recent discussions in textbooks not suitable?

Comment: 50 years is OK. More recent discussions in textbooks are suitable for learning something, but not for citing - don't you think? I would like to give credit to the right people.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with citing a recent text. The texts by Silverman on elliptic curves are often cited even if it's not for a theorem due to Silverman himself, simply because his books are a convenient source to learn about the material covered by them.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I think I will choose Görtz-Wedhorn's text on algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[A. Weil, The field of definition of a variety, Amer. J. Math. 78 (1956), 509-524](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2372670?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents).  Theorem 3.

J-P. Serre, Groupes algébriques et corps de classes,  Publications de l'institut de mathématique de l'université de Nancago, VII. Hermann, Paris 1959.
 Ch. V-20, Prop. 12, Cor. 2.

There is an English translation of Serre's book:
Algebraic Groups and Class Fields (Graduate Texts in Mathematics) 1st ed. 1988. Corr. 2nd printing 1997 Edition.

Weil's paper is 60 years old!  I don't think one can read it now. Serre's book is very useful. The language of algebraic geometry changed between 1956 and 1959 !

Comment: I was looking for a *modern* reference for Galois descent. Your comment gives Görtz-Wedhorn's text. This is exactly what I need!